# Display Recommendation in community

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

I have Salesforce Tabs + VisualForce template for my Community.
I have created two recommendations for my Community.But when I login into the community they are not visible.How do I display Recommendations into community without changing my template.Can anyone please help?